# What is the $\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\sum ^{n-1}_{j=1}\:\frac{3^{\frac{j}{2}}}{j!}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

We want to calculate $\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\sum ^{n-1}_{j=1}\:\frac{3^{\frac{j}{2}}}{j!}\right)$.

After converting the sum to $\sum ^{n-1}_{j=1}\:\frac{\sqrt 3 ^j}{j!}$ once can already recognize that we are dealing with an exponential series. Now, I am struggling to move the indexes to $j=0$ and $n$ so that I could say it has the form of an exponential series, and the limit for $n\to\infty$ is therefore $e^\sqrt 3$. How to move the indexes?

Actually, because of the index moving, the limit is $e^\sqrt 3 -1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $n-1=m$  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{3^{\frac{j}{2}}}{j!}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{(\sqrt3)^j}{j!}$$

Now $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=0}^n\dfrac{x^r}{r!}=\dfrac{x^0}{0!}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\dfrac{x^r}{r!}$